# Oracle: When does a SQL query stop hitting the database?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

Each time I execute a SQL query, typically I get results that will fit onto the screen. If I want to see more results I have to select `Fetch Last Page`

My question is, when I select `Fetch Last Page` is this now hitting the database or is it just the initial query run and the results are stored somewhere, on the client,  to be displayed?

Comment: Are you executing this query in SQLPLUS?

Comment: @abhi PL/SQL Developer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a concept in most tools called the "Fetch size".   This is the number of rows the database will return in a single fetch call.

So for 1000 rows, and a fetch size of 150, you will make 7 trips to the database to fetch data, the last visit "asking" for 150 and only getting 100 back.

This is why most tools will show you an "initial" set of rows rather than the entire set.

How much the *database* must do to satisfy the initial set depends on the query.  For example:

```
select * from t
```

can just grab the first 150 rows it finds to satisfy your fetchsize of 150.

```
select * from t order by my_column
```

must sort (and hence visit) *all* of the rows in the table, before deriving a result that will then be passed to you in the fetchsize you asked for.  That sorted result *might be